# JQuery Googlemap V3 add markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps, marker

I am very confused as to why this would happen..

I am trying to add markers to a map, and it was working fine when I had an alert within one of the functions.  Satisfied that is was working I took out the alert and tested it again, but the markers would not load.  When I put an alert back into the function in the same place that markers are loaded correctly again.  Does anybody know why this would happen, is there some sort of timing issue with my code that I don't understand?  Firebug reported no issues, and the XML file is being loaded correctly.

I posted my entire page of code that I've been working on because I have no clue which portion of the code contains the problem.

However the alert that I was talking about is inside the `get_locations..` function: `alert("THIS HERE");`

```
<style type="text/css" >

  html { height: 100% }

  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

</style>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var alerted = false;

    function MYMAP() 
    {
        //internal
        var map = '';
        var center = '';
        var centerImage = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png';
        var infoWindow = '';
        var last_ne_lat; //Check previous map corner
        var locations = [];

        var customIcons = {
              yes: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
              },
              no: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
              }
        };

        var get_locations = function(neLat, neLng, swLat, swLng, map, infoWindow)
        {
            //testMap.removeAllMarkers();
            var xmlArray = [];
            var tags = '';
            var tagCheck = false;
            /*if($("#tags").val())
            {
                tags = $.trim($("#tags").val());
                tagCheck = true;
                //alert(tags);              
            }
            var coupons= $('#coupons').attr('checked'); 
            //if(coupons == 'checked')
                //alert("Checking for coups");
            //$("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline"); //For checking XML
            */
            $.get('Scripts/googlemap_ajax.php', {neLat: neLat, neLng: neLng, swLat: swLat, swLng: swLng}, 
            function(xml)
            {
                $(xml).find("marker").each(function()
                {
                    var id = $(this).attr("locationID");
                    var name = $(this).attr("name");
                    var tags = $(this).attr('tags');
                    var coupon = $(this).attr('coupon');
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                $(this).attr('latitude'),
                                $(this).attr('longitude'));
                    xmlArray.push({"id": id, "marker": "empty", "name": name, "point": point, "tags": tags, "coupon": coupon});
                });
            }, "xml");

            var addElements = [];
            var removeElements = [];

            alert("THIS HERE");

            $.each(locations, function(i, v1)
            {
                var inLoop = false;
                loc=this;
                $.each(xmlArray, function(j,v)
                {
                    if(loc.id == this.id)
                    {
                        inLoop = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                }); 
                if(!inLoop)
                {
                    removeElements.push(i);
                } 
            });

            for(var i=removeElements.length-1; i>=0; i = i-1)
            {
                locations[removeElements[i]][marker].setMap(null);
                locations.splice(removeElements[i],1);
            }   

            $.each(xmlArray, function(i, v1)
            {
                var inLoop = false;
                xml=this;
                $.each(locations, function(j,v)
                {
                    if(xml.id == this.id)
                    {
                        inLoop = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                }); 
                if(!inLoop)
                {
                    addElements.push(i);
                } 
            });


            $.each(addElements, function()
            {
                var icon = customIcons[xmlArray[this].coupon] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: xmlArray[this].point,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon.icon
                    });
                var html = "<h3>"+xmlArray[this].name+"</h3><p>"+xmlArray[this].tags+"</p>";

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(html);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

                xmlArray[this].marker = marker;
                locations.push(xmlArray[this]);
            });                     

        };


    //external:
    return {
            init: function(selector, latLng, zoom) 
            {
                var myOptions = {
                        zoom:zoom,
                        center: latLng,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
            },

            centerMarker: function(latlng) 
            {
                this.center = new google.maps.Marker({

                position: latlng,

                map: this.map,

                icon: centerImage,

                title: "You are here"

                });
            },

            removeAllMarkers: function() 
            {
                $.each(locations, function() 
                {
                    this.marker.setMap(null);
                });
                locations=[];
            },


            addBoundChange: function() 
            {
                this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                test = this.map;
                test2 = this.infoWindow;
                // Add listener to map
                google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                    var zoom_level = this.getZoom();
                    if(zoom_level > 12)
                    {
                        var bounds = this.getBounds();
                        var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
                        var neLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
                        var neLng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
                                var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
                        var swLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
                        var swLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
                        if( neLat != last_ne_lat)
                        {
                            last_ne_lat = neLat;    
                            get_locations(neLat, neLng, swLat, swLng, test, test2);

                        }
                    }
                    else //Alerts the user only once- removes markers everytime
                    {
                        testMap.removeAllMarkers();
                        if(!alerted)    
                        { 
                            alerted=true;
                            alert("Please zoom in to continue displaying the location markers");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        };
    }
    var testMap = new MYMAP();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>,<?php echo $long; ?>);
    testMap.init('#map_canvas', latlng, 16);
    testMap.centerMarker(latlng);
    testMap.addBoundChange();

    $('#tagSearch').submit(function(e)
    {   
        e.preventDefault();
    });



});
</script>


<body>
    <form id="tagSearch">
        <h3>Filter results:</h3>
        Search: <input type="text" id="tags" />&nbsp
        <input type="checkbox" id="coupons" /> deals only<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form> 

    <div id="locationSelect" style="width:100%"></div>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:70%; height:90%"></div>

</body>
```

-----------------------------------------SOLVED------------------------------------------

Ok, so the problem was that the code chunk after the `$.get` function was being processed before the `$.get` request was completed.

The solution was to throw all of the code after the `$.get` into a `.complete()` chain:

```
var get_locations = function(neLat, neLng, swLat, swLng, map, infoWindow)
{
    $.get('url', {data: "data"}, 
    function(xml)
    {
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function()
        {
            //Process data
        });
    }, "xml")
    .complete(function()
    {
         //Code that relies on the processed data
    });
};
```

Comment: You might want to add your solution as an answer - its OK to answer your own questions - that way you'll not waste other people's time who read through this quite long question only to find its solved at the end.

Comment: @nickdos - I was planning on doing it earlier when I solved it a few hours after posting, but Stack Overflow said since I'm so new to the site, I can't answer the question until 8 hours after posting. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that the code chunk after the $.get function was being processed before the $.get request was completed.

The solution was to throw all of the code after the $.get into a .complete() chain:

```
var get_locations = function(neLat, neLng, swLat, swLng, map, infoWindow)
{
    $.get('url', {data: "data"}, 
    function(xml)
    {
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function()
        {
            //Process data
        });
    }, "xml")
    .complete(function()
    {
         //Code that relies on the processed data
    });
};
```